# makefile link several lib contained in same folder

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a folder witch contains several dynamic library

```
path/librairie/libfile_1.so
path/librairie/libfile_2.so
```

I am trying to link those dynamic library to my output program. I tried the following code but it dosent work..

```
COMPILE: $(OBJ) $(LIB)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -L/path/librairie -l./librairie -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(OUTPUT)
```

Does somebody can help me ?
Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `-l./librairie` option is supposed to do.  You pass the name of the libraries you want to link with `-l`, you don't pass a path or directory name.

You want:

```
$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(OUTPUT): $(OBJ) $(LIB)
        $(CC) $(OBJ) -L/path/librairie -lfile_1 -lfile_2 -o $@
```

Comment: hi @MadScientist, thank you for answer. This way works. But lets suppose that I have thousand lib that I want link to the output. Is there a general way to link all lib contained in the folder ??

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to just "grab all the libraries".  For shared libraries it's not so bad, but certainly for static libraries you have to list them in a specific order, because the linker is a single-pass linker so order matters.  However, if you want to do it it's not hard.  Something like: `$(patsubst lib%.so,-l%,$(notdir $(wildcard path/librairie/lib*.so)))`